# How do I see if something is getting touched?

Tags: objective-c

Is there some way in objective C to see if an instance is being touched such as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      if (recordButton.touched = YES) {
          NSLog (@"record button got touched");
      }
}
```

Can't they just make these things easy?

Could someone help?

Comment: This is not a language issue, but a framework issue. So you should clarify what framework and version you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create a custom button, right click, and connect touchUp with your function

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about a UIButton in UIKit. To tell when a button is pressed, give the button an action with [`-[UIControl addTarget:action:forControlEvents:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:).

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIView` inherits from `UIResponder`, you can use [`touchesBegan:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:)